# php - curl empty response while browser display json output

Tags: php, json, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Clean%20Bandit%20-%20Rather%20Be&entity=song&limit=10&lang=fr_fr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
        echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
    $CurResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo 'Result:'.$CurResult;
```

Comment: do not know how, but I just copypaste your code and receive "Bad Request" response

Comment: Maybe because of     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
Makes your request a post, and it should be a get right?

Comment: first time i also get "Bad Request", but after try different curl and testing now i am only get empty result, while in browser you can see json response.

Comment: Could you try commenting the line I mentioned? i"m not sure but that's the main difference between the browser and the CURL request in this case

Comment: i removed curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); but still empty result.

Comment: @MathijsSegers seems to be right... should give it a try

Comment: I copied your code, removed the post param and it works, but if it doesn't work then I really don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Clean%20Bandit%20-%20Rather%20Be&entity=song&limit=10&lang=fr_fr';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($content);
```

Use this code to get the response curl is not needed in this case

Comment: this giving warning Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? its also not working

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Clean%20Bandit%20-%20Rather%20Be&entity=song&limit=10&lang=fr_fr): failed to open stream: No error in

Answer (score 0):

from php manual

```
curl_errno()
```

does not return true or false, it returns error number 0, if no errors.
so you either change the condition to

```
if(curl_errno($ch)!=0)
```

or use `curl_error()`

```
if(curl_error($ch)!=''){
    echo "error: ".curl_error($ch);
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php

Comment: unless 0 is auto casted to boolean (false), not sure but it worth a try

Comment: ok thanks, i used if(curl_error($ch)!=''){
    echo "error: ".curl_error($ch);
} but still empty response